# Cant define Selenium chrome driver path

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I write automation system and perfectly works in localhost, but when i try to publish it and upload to server. I got this error;

```
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

And I am 1 billion sure of this path, here is my code

```
            var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            var options = new ChromeOptions();                
            var driverPath = Path.Combine(outPutDirectory, "ChromeDriverInThisFolder\\");
            string driver_path = new Uri(driverPath).LocalPath;
            driver = new ChromeDriver(driver_path, options);
```

My server is windows Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64
 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: in server where you have put chromedriver.exe?

Comment: @TeknoBilSoft, the message is pretty clear: chromedriver.exe is not in "D:\PathTo".

Comment: Have you tried without passing the path? just "driver = new ChromeDriver(options);" ?

Comment: I do, then i get this error ; Additional information: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

Comment: can you please move chromedriver to c: and  then change path in cod e and then try.

Comment: When I do that I got this error ; unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: The problem is that ChromeDriver isn't installed in the Server.

Comment: Or, at least, the CromeDriver server is not finding the chromedriver.exe. The path you are passing is for the chrome itself, not for the chromedriver.exe

Comment: @Jauch but I am also writing this ; var options = new ChromeOptions(); options.BinaryLocation = @"exactAdressChrome.exeHere"; still no response, It might be security thing i guess

Comment: The question is that "BinaryLocation is for the Chrome, not the ChromeDriver. I'm pretty convinced that the server is not finding your chromedriver.exe because it is not where it would expect it do be...

Comment: Waint... Now it the Chrome Binary that it do not find? BEfore it was ChromeDriver, not?

Comment: @Jauch Not really, because if driver get path error it sends this error message ; The file C:\blablabla\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66812/discussion-between-jauch-and-teknobilsoft).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "standard location" of chrome, this way:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
// all of your 'options.AddArgument(...);' here
driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //This will look for chrome in the default directory
```

If you need to pass a chrome binary in a different directory you can use this way:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
// all of your 'options.AddArgument(...);' here
options.setBinary("pathToYourOtherBinary"); //This is for CHROME binary, not ChromeDriver binary
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

After some research, [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), I'm tempted to say that you don't have ChromeDriver on your server.

It should be somewhere on your AppData like this:

Windows XP  %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Windows Vista   C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Donwload ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and install it on your server. Than the first option (whithout the path) will work.

Comment: Yes I add ;  options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"; still no progress :\

Comment: This is the default location. Use the first option, without defining the location.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer. Did you downloaded to the server the ChromeDriver?

Comment: When I do that I got this error ; unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Exactly. You don't have chromedriver on your server.

Comment: You can download it from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Yea I uploaded whole project with source codes files just incase. ( I tried publishing way too before)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66811/discussion-between-jauch-and-teknobilsoft).